# How do you respawn the Ender Dragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I heard that you can respawn the ender dragon but I don't know how. Can someone please tell me? I tried putting end crystals on the pillars but it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the Final Portal.
2. Defeat the dragon
3. Put 4 end crystals on the portal

[image: How to respawn the ender dragon]